# kentico custom settings not accessible

Tags: kentico

I have added some custom settings to Kentico 7.0.50
However I can no longer locate them in Site Manager. I have tried using Settings->Custom Settings and looing in the navigation tree. I have also tried Development -> custom settings.

I can locate them by using the search ability in Settings->Custom Settings, and I see that they are several levels deep  ( heading like  Custom Settings> Site Name -> Category Name > Social Networks > Global )  I cant edit the setting when it is located in this manner.

How can I find and edit the custom setting?

Comment: Do you see "Custom settings" node in Site Manager -> Settings?

Comment: it turned out the data was corrupt. I restored a backup.  I aren't sure how it got corrupt.  I changed a group that a setting belonged to and it seemed to go bad from there.

Comment: @kirsteng: You should add your comment as an answer to your own question and mark it as the accepted answer in that case.

Comment: That wouldn't properly explain why it happened or how to fix it.  Reverting to back up is not really an answer